# Spring RestTemplate Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization, resttemplate

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string to a List of MyClass but getting this exception:

java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token

MyClass has a public string getter/setter for each attribute in the JSON string that I am getting back from the server:

[{"PublicIP":"1.1.1.1","PrivateIP":"1.1.1.1","InstanceId":"i-1234","IsRunning":false}]

Here is the code calling the server:

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyClass>> response =
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:5000/api/cloud/thelist",
HttpMethod.GET, null, 
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
```

Here is the MyClass bean:

```
public class MyClass {

private String PublicIP;
private String PrivateIP;
private String InstanceId;
private boolean IsRunning;

public String getPublicIP() {
    return PublicIP;
}

public void setPublicIP(String publicIP) {
    PublicIP = publicIP;
}

public String getPrivateIP() {
    return PrivateIP;
}

public void setPrivateIP(String privateIP) {
    PrivateIP = privateIP;
}

public String getInstanceId() {
    return InstanceId;
}

public void setInstanceId(String instanceId) {
    InstanceId = instanceId;
}

public boolean isIsRunning() {
    return IsRunning;
}

public void setIsRunning(boolean isRunning) {
    IsRunning = isRunning;
}
}
```

The return string is a List and also I have the setter methods.  Am I missing some configuration that tells how to deserialize this object?

Comment: Are you *sure* the response content is what you think it is, i.e. *that* JSON text? E.g. if you use that URL in a web browser, then do "view source" on the result, you see exactly that JSON?

Comment: Andreas, yes that is the exact text I see when I post the URL in a browser.  I actually copied it from a browser into this question.  That is why I am so stumped because it is valid JSON.  There must be some other configuration needed for this to work but in all of the examples I have seen nothing is mentioned.  I wonder if I am missing a dependency in my pom....just brainstorming.  Thank you for looking a my question.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you do the "view source" I mentioned? I ask, because the web browser may have prettified the JSON response, and the error indicates that the response is a string literal when a `List` is expected, so the entire response seems to be encoded as a string literal, i.e. `"[{\"PublicIP\":\"1.1.1.1\",\"PrivateIP\":\"1.1.1.1\",\"InstanceId\":\"i-1234\",\"IsRunning\":false}]"`, and unencoded by web browser for display. --- Or `MyClass` has `PublicIP`, `PrivateIP`, or `InstanceId` defined as a `List`, but that seems too obvious for you to miss.

Comment: Andreas, I missed your point.  I did a view source and it was just the JSON above.

Comment: Then please show us `MyClass` so we can see if it's something there causing the problem.

Comment: Andreas, I added MyClass.  This class is so simple, just a bean contain String attributes and accessors but I hope you see something wrong.

Comment: value for isRunning field is not string it is boolean, could you change MyClass accordingly and recheck?@plex4r

Comment: I had it as a boolean initially but changed it to a string to try and get this to work.  "true" or "false" should be valid strings.

Comment: I changed the field to boolean.  I see your point now, that it is not a String.  It sill failed with the same error.  Starting an attribute with "Is" looks like a bad choice to me because of the strange names it creates for getters (isIsRunning).  I wonder if that could be causing issues.  I do not have control over this choice.